# XSLT: comma separation and custom ordering

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the following file (its structure should not be changed):

```
<file>
    <one>First</one>
    <three>Third</three>
    <two>Second</two>
    <five>Fifth</five>
</file>
```

I am looking for XSLT tranformation which gives the following output (custom ordering + comma separation):

> First, Second, Third, Fifth

I am to define the ordering manually:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="one">
<xsl:apply-templates select="two">
<xsl:apply-templates select="three">
<xsl:apply-templates select="four">
<xsl:apply-templates select="five">
```

Note that element `<four>` is missing in the original file!

Unfortunately, the commonly used approach for comma separation

```
<xsl:for-each select="one|two|three|four|five">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

will not work in this case. Of course, I could use `xsl:sort` with some sorting criteria...

But maybe there is a simple and elegant solution, is there?

Comment: Well, if you can use XSLT 2 or 3 you can use `<xsl:apply-templates select="one, two, three, four, five"/>` and then your approach with e.g. `<xsl:template match="file/*"><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if></xsl:template>` would work although simply using `<xsl:value-of select="one, two, three, four, five" separator=", "/>` is easier.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate about how it didn't work?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Unfortunately, I am restricted to XSLT 1.0.   @Steve The problem with for-each approach is that it ignores the ordering (if I am not using `xsl:sort`)

Comment: If you're asking questions about XSLT 1.0 please tag them as such. It's now a legacy language variant and some of us like to filter which technologies we are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, if you can use XSLT 2.0 you can do this....

```
<xsl:for-each select="one,two,three,four,five">
```

In XSLT 1.0 though, one approach would be two do something like this..

```
    <xsl:for-each select="one|two|three|four|five">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before('|one|two|three|four|five|', concat('|', local-name(), '|')))" />
```

Or, maybe slightly simpler in this case...

```
    <xsl:for-each select="one|two|three|four|five">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before('onetwothreefourfive',local-name()))" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For elements `one` through `four`, if the element exists you want a comma following its value, and if the element does not exist you want no comma.

It's easy to handle this by emitting the comma within the responsible template, since the corresponding template will be evaluated if and only if the matching element exists.

I'd write

```
<xsl:template match="one|two|three|four">
  <xsl:value-of select="string()"/>
  <xsl:text>, </
</
<xsl:template match="five">
  <xsl:value-of select="string()"/>
</
```